# Find total count of HIT and MISS using ID and skipping duplicate based on another row in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like-

```
    id---------rowNum------status
    aa23       1            HIT
    aa23       1            HIT
    aa23       1            HIT
    aa23       2            MISS
    aa23       2            MISS
    aa24       2            MISS
    aa24       2            MISS
```

So basically I need to get the count of and HIT and MISS given the ID

For example-
if I am given aa23 I should return

```
    status-----count
    HIT          1
    MISS         1
```

The rowNums should be distinct so given id=aa23 the HIT occurs thrice but all are rowNum 1 so should be counted once same for Miss

Comment: The example is a bit scant. Please add more rownums and ids.

Comment: try `GROUP BY id,rowNum,status`

Comment: Have added more details. Apologies for the vague example

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @nbk Yes that is not producing the expected result. I need the HIT and MISS where id=xyz GROUP BY Status and need to make sure the row_num is DISTINCT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could elemente all duplicates first and also only select the id you want and the count the resulting rows

```
create table mytable (
  id varchar(10),
  rowNum int,
  status varchar(10)
);

insert into mytable values
('aa23' ,1 ,'HIT'),
('aa23' ,1 ,'HIT'),
('aa23' ,1 ,'HIT'),
('aa23' ,2 ,'MISS'),
('aa23' ,2 ,'MISS'),
('aa24' ,2 ,'MISS'),
('aa24' ,2 ,'MISS');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 7
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT DISTINCT id,rowNum,status
  FROM mytable)
SELECT id, status, COUNT(*) as count_
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id, status
```

| id | status | count_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa24 | MISS | 1 |
| aa23 | HIT | 1 |
| aa23 | MISS | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/My8wBZgd)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by` as follows :

```
with cte as (
  select id, rowNum, status
  from mytable
  where id = 'aa23'
  group by id, rowNum, status
)
select status, count(1) 
from cte
group by status;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/l_1sSNZt)